# What is the meaning of Dot after TLD?

Tags: domain-name-system, tld

Id like to create a CNAME-Entry in `strato.de`

This is the warning i have:

[image]

The meaning is "The Server name must end with a point after the top-level domain".

I used `xxx.googlehosted.com.` and **it works great!**

But why? Is a absolute-servername always ending with a dot?

Funny thing, i noticed https://www.google.com./search?site=&q=test works great!

Comment: A very informative community discussion can be found on this superuser question. Do check it out: https://superuser.com/questions/1467958/why-does-putting-a-dot-after-the-url-remove-login-information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FQDNs consist of a hierachy of subdomains or *labels*. The individual labels are delimited by a dot.

The top level domain is actually **not** the TLD, but the DNS root domain, which is nameless, hence just the dot. Next comes the TLD, like .com .net .de, etc. Then come more levels of subdomains.

A different way of looking at it is that the subdomain to the right site of the dot has authority over the subdomain to the left site of the dot. So the DNS root domain has authority over the TLDs, then the TLDs have authority over what most people call 'the domain' (like .google), and then the entity that owns that domain has authority over the subdomains (.mail.google), and so on.

See wikipedia for more:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Domain_name_syntax